# Users' Google Analytics ID changes when a link opens in new tab

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

Users' Google Analytics ID changes when a link opens in new tab. Does anyone have an idea why it may happen?
[image]

Comment: What part of the cookie is different?

Comment: The _ga ID changes. For exemple GA1.1.1893432208.1708957689.

Comment: Couple more basic questions...Does the user stay on the same site or a different one? Is it a subdomain? Are the analytics properties the same on the new destination page?

Comment: Yes, user stay on the same site with the same domain. GA proprieties are the same on both pages.
You can check if you want by clicking on one of the images on this page  https://tile.expert/en-gb/catalogue/brick-effect

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two different `gtag` that are appearing/firing at various levels of the site. On the initial page, there is a `G-XXXXXXGF8V`. On the landing page, there is also a Google Ads and remarketing tag `AW-XXXXXXXXXX` that fires which is creating a separate `_ga` cookie on the user's machine.

Comment: Do I understand correctly - Google Remarketing tag create a _ga cookie? Any ideas why this happens and how to avoid it?

Comment: There are two different analytics tags: one general and one related to Ads. The ads tracking will create a _ga cookie associated with that property alongside the one for the GA4 property.

Comment: In this case I should see an increased number of GA cookies when opening the link in a new tab, right? but that's not true. I see the same number of GA cookies but with different identifiers.
An important remark - the problem only occurs in the Safari browser.

Comment: Honestly, I don't have those browsers so I cannot test it. What I do know is there are two different analytics on the page(s): `G-XXXXXXXXXX` and `AW-XXXXXXXXXX`. Each of those should be creating a specific `_ga` cookie that is applicable to their property. These do not change their values for Chrome. There are also issues with the implementation of GTM. There doesn't appear to be any code between the `<noscript>` tags after the opening of the body. So with non-standard implementation, it could always be a little quirky.

Comment: There could also be things impacting it on Safari. I know that Mac has implemented some enhanced privacy on their devices/software so that could also be impacting cookie creation. I just don't know a lot about it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all this moments. I didn't find the issues with the implementation of GTM. There are three dots between the <noscript> tags after the opening of the body. If you click on them the code appears.

Comment: It is appearing now and Tag Assistant is now seeing it properly installed.